# Ubuntu not forwarding traffic between 2 interfaces

Tags: linux

I have a simple network
Both Linux machines are ubuntu.

Linux #1 (eth0:192.168.1.10) <---> Linux #2 (eth1: 192.168.1.11)  + --- + (eth2: 192.168.2.10) + --- + FW (192.168.2.11)

Basically, I want traffic from Linux #1 to go out on the internet and I think I need to make Linux #2 as a router. What is working

From Linux #1, I can ping 192.168.1.11 and 192.168.2.10 and I cant ping 192.168.2.11.

I enabled sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 on Linux #2 and also turned off firewall 
service ufw stop.

On Linux#1, I have the following 
route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.11      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

On Linux#2, I have the following

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.11     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: your FW is probably missing route for 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.2.11 from Linux#2? Your setup looks like it should work...

Comment: Yes I can ping 192.168.2.11 from Linux #2.  no problem.

Comment: `also turned off firewall`, are you sure you don't need NAT?  (ie a MASQ rule?

Comment: May be I need a NAT but before that I am trying to get one step at a time. I understand I need a static route on the firewall. The firewall has 192.168.2.11 on interface 4.  So i added a static route like this                                                                  destination (192.168.1.0/24)  interface(1/4), next hop (192.168.2.10). But still the ping from Linux #1 does not go through.

Comment: There was an issue on the firewall.  I fixed that and now i can ping from Linux #1 to FW interface 192.168.2.11. Next let me try the NAT rule on Linux #2 and get back if i cant figure it out.

Comment: I found this article http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html and now my NAT rule works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network configuration seems ok.

I think what you are missing here is an SNAT rule (or interface Masquerading as it is some times called) on your Linux #2 computer. I recommend backing up your IPTables and using something along these lines:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to 192.168.2.11

http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.1

I think packet reaches .2.11 but doesnt find it's way back to Linux #1 due to the source address specified in the packet. This ensures the packet has a source address 192.168.2.11 so it appears to Linux #1 as the packet it is expecting.